# BitTorrent library for Java WITH selecting files after loading torrent

Tags: java, bittorrent

I'm looking for a torrent client library for Java. What I need is a library that supports the 'uTorrent' like selector after a torrent is loaded.

Like when you download a .torrent-file, and load it in uTorrent, it gives you a list with selection boxes to select the files you want to download.

Couldn't find that so fast, so maybe anyone knows about?

Comment: My idea of a torrent client library would be a library that provides you with the support of p2p protocol and a parser for .torrent files - at a stretch. What you seem to be looking is a UI??

Comment: Yes but it could let me select the files from the torrent, through functionality in the library, that I want to download

Comment: @Highmastdon did you find any compatible library, I'm working on ttorrent by Turn, thought that you could help me?

Comment: @NitinMisra Currently I'm busy with a job and stuff, but you can always share a repository so I can look when I've got time

Answer (score 0):

It's possible in Azureus, but it might be a lot of effort to turn the functionality into a library.